# Getting the image of a source from a website and adding it to embed image discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I get an image from a website when the image is random every time? For example the website I want to get the images from is https://nekos.life/ and each time you reload the site, The image is different. How can I get the image and add it as an image on embed?

Comment: What [mcve] have you tried and why doesn't it work? Please [edit] these details into your question. As well, please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Python API wrapper?

https://github.com/Nekos-life/nekos.py

Install

```
pip install nekos.py
```

Usage example

```
import nekos
print(nekos.cat())

>>> 'https://cdn.nekos.life/meow/04D5A.jpg'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but nekos.py is having errors, Whenever I try using the api I get this error "Couldn't contact the API right now..."

Comment: @Phoenix I didn't download the lib, but the API seems fine. Eg. https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow

Comment: You can request that link and get the url from the json response